# Error in creating triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have  created a  trigger  like  below.
But it  shows  me  a  error.

```
 2/30    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
          := ; not null default character
```

Can anyone  help me solving  this?
Thanks  in advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADRAKLIVE.TRG_HELPDESK
AFTER UPDATE
OF STATUS
ON ADRAKLIVE.TBL_SERVICEREPORT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     declare ts varchar2(10) = :'YES';
 UPDATE tbl_ithelpdesk
       SET it_closed  =: ts
     WHERE call_no = :NEW.call_no;
END;
```

Comment: The use of the variable ts seems to be bad practice here. Just set it_closed = 'YES'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your trigger is malformed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_HELPDESK
AFTER UPDATE
OF STATUS
ON TBL_SERVICEREPORT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
declare
  ts varchar2(10) := 'YES';
BEGIN
 UPDATE tbl_ithelpdesk
       SET it_closed  = ts
     WHERE call_no = :NEW.call_no;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your trigger to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADRAKLIVE.TRG_HELPDESK
AFTER UPDATE
OF STATUS
ON ADRAKLIVE.TBL_SERVICEREPORT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   ts varchar2(10);
BEGIN
 ts := 'YES';
 UPDATE tbl_ithelpdesk
       SET it_closed  =: ts
     WHERE call_no = :NEW.call_no;
END;
```

Comment: I get this errorPLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]
5/9     PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
5/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored